# Replace AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, appdelegate

I just have a Objective-C project and I want to use AppDelegate to access to my xcdatamodel, but when I add `AppDelegate.swift` to my project it show me a compile problem, it is error because it doesn't know what AppDelegate use and what is the main. Then I tried to delete `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` and add `AppDelegate.swift`, but it also doesn't work and still has compile errors.
How I can add `AppDelegate.swift` to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `AppDelegate.swift` instead of `AppDelegate.h` / `AppDelegate.m`, you should add the Swift file to your project and delete the `.h` and `.m` files (don't forget to click yes when asked about the bridging header). In addition, you should also delete `main.m` since it is not needed anymore and will cause a linker error.

Comment: Glad I could help! If this is the answer you were looking for, you can choose it as the correct one.

Comment: But I have new compile problem it need main.m file to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Teo is correct. To solve the main.m file compile problem add @UIApplicationMain above the class declaration

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create a new Xcode project with Swift as default and check out the AppDelegate code in that one and copy/adapt it over to your project.